# Conditional formatting -- but seems to be outside the scope of types provided

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Version: Office 365

Is it possible to set the background color of a cell based on the DATE value in another cell? It seems like Conditional Formatting should handle this, but the choices under "Select a Rule Type" don't seem to include what I need. To begin with, I thought the 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format' choice sounded good, but what do I enter in the 'Format values where this formula is true' box to, say, set the backcolor to green if the value is within a given range, else to white?

I'll probably need to provide more information...but what?  Please let me know what more you (someone) may need. This just seems to me to be outside the few choices provided.

Thanks!

Comment: Start by writing an example of your Data and conditions

Answer (score 1):

One method that will work is:
Highlight the data you want to apply the conditional formatting to.
Choose  Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula...
Enter the following formula:

```
=AND(DATEVALUE(TEXT(E3,"mm/dd/yyyy"))>DATEVALUE("3/1/2010"),DATEVALUE(TEXT(E3,"mm/dd/yyyy"))<DATEVALUE("3/21/2010"))
```

Change the dates to your needs, prefix the cell references with a dollar sign if the range for the conditional formatting spans more than one column, and change "E3" to the cells that contain the dates.
I tested this in my own Excel Office 365.